# Can a Windows Time Limit App, bump a game out of Full Screen (DirectX?) mode when time is up?

Tags: directx

I work on software that keeps track of time (C++/MFC), and when time is up (after a handful of warnings as the time limit approaches), we need to bump the person off of the computer.

Works great with Windows apps, however, it seems that a fair number of games, typically when they are in full screen mode, can be played even after we've done our work to hide other windows and/or swap to another desktop.

I know nothing about DirectX, and since I know nothing about it, I'm eager to blame it. :-)

My assumption is that when in some kind of "DirectX" mode, the game is interacting with the hardware and whatever the Windows API is doing, the game and the video hardware could care less.

The problem is that I have unhappy parents who thought our software was going to be effective and it's not.

DirectX/Game Guru's, Is there a way that my Windows App can give the game "the boot" when time is up, forcing the Windows desktop to be displayed, pausing the game, or at least detecting that we're in a hopeless situation with the display mode being in full-screen DirectX mode which can't be programatically switched out of?

Comment: How are you currently causing these games to quit? While many DX games do not use the message pump for keyboard/mouse input, they should still listen to a WM_QUIT message.

Comment: We initially took the stance of not logging the person off and not forcing quits of applications, mainly because we didn't want to have the wrath of parents complaining that the kids didn't save their 30 page history paper when time ran out and we forced quit or forced log off.  ;-)  Though we do allow a parent to specify apps that can be forced to quit.